# SonarQube: Refactor this getter/setter so that it actually refers to the field '_selectedType' C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube and I am getting this error Refactor this getter/setter so that it actually refers to the field '_selectedType' how do I refactor this to make the error go away in sonarQube. This is how the code is:

```
public string SelectedType
{ 
  get => _selectedType;
  set 
  {
      if(SetProperty(ref _selectedType, value))
      {  
         Load(value);
      }
   }
}
```

So where the _selectedType is I am getting errors one for setter and one for the getter. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like this getter/setter is doing too much. Why don't you make it a simple getter/setter and decouple/externalize the other logic?

`public string SelectedType { get { return _selectedType; } set { _selectedType = value; }}`

Comment: Its a false/positive. Add `//NOSONAR` or `//NOPMD`  to the end of the lines you want to ignore.

Comment: @user2966445 doing that is giving me the same error